# Computing Jacobian of $T(z,t) = (zt, z(1-t))$

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

For $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $T(z,t) = (tz, (1-t)z)$, how does one use Mathematica to compute the Jacobian matrix of $T$ (to then compute its determinant)? Suppose $(z,t)$ are fixed.

Comment: (1) Search doc center for [Jacobian](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=jacobian) > ["Differentiation"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Differentiation.html) or [`D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) > "Details and Options", and then search for Jacobian. (2)  Search doc center for [determinant](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=determinant) > [`Det`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Det.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
f[z_, t_] := {t z, z (1 - t)};
j = {D[f[z, t], z], D[f[z, t], t]}
Det[j]
-z
```

As Carl Woll points out, you can express this somewhat more concisely as:

```
j = D[f[z, t], {{z, t}}]
```

Comment: I think the canonical method is `D[f[z, t], {{z, t}}]`.

Comment: Your answer generates `{{t, 1-t}, {z, -z}}`, while the "canonical" answer generates `{{t,z}, {1-t, -z}}`. Which one is it?

Comment: The two answers differ by a Transpose... so basically, which order you want to take the derivatives.